# How to improve the resolution of EffectComposer in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, resolution, post-processing

I am using EffectComposer to apply skin effect to my avatar. However, the final resolution looks quite blurry compared to the version without post-processing. I have tried to change pixelRatio setting, but without much success.

I'm using the code in the following example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_normalmap.html

[image: Left: w/o EffectComposer render | Right: with EffectComposer render]

**Update:**
I compared two different implementations of the same normal map example from THREE.js where I could see different resolution qualities. I figured that setting **renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio)** (which equals 2) allowed the model to fit the screen but the looking blurry (especially as you zoom out). However, if renderer.setPixelRatio is not set, a standard value of 1 is applied, causing the model to become sharper but only rendered at about 25% of the window size.

[image]

Below a better image to compare the sharpness/resolution. The one on the right is way sharper than the one on the left.

[image]

I need the sharper version being rendered at the full size of the window.

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WebGL doesn't support antialiasing when rendering to render targets. There are additional post processing effects you can apply to compensate for it though.
Additonally, there may be issues with EffectsComposer and antialiasing.
I haven't looked into it deeply myself but check out these threads:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/568

https://github.com/openworm/org.geppetto.frontend/issues/724

and

https://github.com/openworm/org.geppetto.frontend/pull/728

Comment: It puzzles me that the threejs example looks so clear and I'm using the same code. This problem shouldn't affect the example as well?

Comment: You make a good point. There might very well be something else wrong with your app. Are you using the FXAA effect, and have you changed anything in the setup except switching to your model?

Comment: I was comparing the same example from a previous version of Threejs and I figured that what is making the difference is the setting of devicePixelRatio. The blurred result has the line "renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );", the sharper result has not. However, the sharper result now renders the object at about 25% of the whole window. I'll update my question with the images. I had a separate post addressing this problem, only now I connected the dots. I still can't find a way to sharpen the model and render it at window size.

Comment: Oh you're really close then! You just have to find where your code updates the renderer.setSize on window size change. And multiply the width and height by the new pixel ratio you set!

Comment: Could you exemplify this change? 
The code I'm using adds renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ) right after setting renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); in init(), and also inside onWindowResize after camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); and before composer.setSize( width, height );

Comment: Switching between effectFXAA.renderToScreen = true; and     effectColor.renderToScreen = true; also causes the rendering to have different qualities. The former is sharper but only render at 1/4 of the window. The later has lower quality but render on the full size of the window.

Comment: I don't think you want them to render to screen because then subsequent render effect passes wont be operating on the output of those passes. Only the final pass should render to screen.

What you're doing is sorta the inverse of what is described at the last of the "Things to keep in mind" section here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_best_practices

So I'm thinking you may want to set the render size to 2x what your window size is, and then right after set the canvas css width/height to the window size.